# Logfiles for non terminating processes

Tags: linux, logs

I am writing a program that is designed to never terminate, It will also produce large logs (files) of what it is doing. What I would like is for a linux process to periodically (every X minutes (cronjob?)) :

1. Take the current logs from the current log file
2. place them in a separate file (appropriately named) for offline storage / removal
3. Truncate the current logfile so data is not duplicated.

All *without data loss or interruption* to the producing program.
So that I end up with a sequence of time delimeted logs

Is there a Linux utility or known solution for this ? or should I build this logging functionality into the program ?

Comment: "without interruption" - do you mean you're not even allowed to send a signal to the process?

Comment: @Mat preferrably yes, but i will listen to other options! More generally i would like it to be "Without significant suspension or downtime"

Comment: Keep things simple, just output to stdout/err and have some [process supervision software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision) (e.g. `systemd`, Upstart, `daemontools`, `runit`,...) handle logging.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid stdout etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux uses `syslogd` for managing log files. I've not used this personally, so I'm not sure what the gotchas might be, but essentially you just send messages to the log and the deamon takes care of the file rotation etc.

See here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog

You would configure `/etc/syslog.conf` to route your messages to a particular file, and you can manually rotate the logs using `logrotate`, also, I think, or set up a cron job.

Comment: This is a good answer because syslog is very flexible. There are multiple implementations, and you can (for example) divert certain classes of log messages to other systems (logging hosts) without having to re-architect your source program.

Comment: This looks like the best approach, however if i understand the manpages correctly, am i limited to 8 LOG_LOCAL logs ? (In cas i want to run more than 8 processes using this logging feature!)

Comment: I believe your eight processes should use the same "facility" but different "ident" strings. You can then configure syslog.conf to do whatever you choose. Anyway, would it be a problem if all the messages got into the same file? Each line would be prefixed with the unique ident.

Comment: Ah, no, I see what you mean. You can only select on the facilty, not the ident; I misunderstood that. Hmmm, that's not ideal if you want separate files. Looks like all your processes are expected to share the same file in this scheme. :(

Comment: Thanks, It is the correct answer according to my Question. Ill probably use this for System (group of processes) level logging as it wont be a problem to have all of them in a log, but leave process specific logs for another mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Usually daemons just writes logs and nothing more. Log rotating is a job of another software. 
Usually it does [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) or similar software.